# Implement SEO to Meteor app the right way

Tags: meteor, seo

I was trying to find the right way to implement SEO in your Meteor app, but can't find any good examples. I feel like what I'm doing is working, but to some extent and could be way better. This is what I'm doing for SEO in my [Meteor app](http://spotifytube.com):

1. Packages I use: spiderable, gadicohen:sitemaps, manuelschoebel:ms-seo
2. Head Tag :

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
 <meta name="google" value="notranslate" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
 <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
 <meta name="google-site-verification" content="google-verification-id" />
 <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="bing-verification-id" />
</head>
```

3. This is what I'm doing using [ms-seo package](https://github.com/DerMambo/ms-seo): In seo.js file:

```js
SeoCollection = new Mongo.Collection('SeoCollection');

Meteor.startup(function() {
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
        return SEO.config({
            title: ’title',
            meta: {
                    'description': ’siteDescription',
                    'keywords': ‘keyword, keyword, keyword',
                    'charset': 'utf-8',
                    'site_name': ’siteName',
                    'url':'http://siteName.com',
                    'viewport': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no',
                    'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=edge,chrome=1',
                    'HandheldFriendly': 'true',
                    'apple-mobile-web-app-capable' : 'yes',
                    'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style': 'black',
                    'referrer': 'never',
              },
              og: {
                    'title': ’siteTitle',
                    'description': ’siteDescription',
                    'image': 'image.png',
                    'type': 'website',
                    'locale': 'en_us',
                    'site_name': 'siteName',
                    'url': 'http://sitename.com'
              },
            rel_author: 'https://plus.google.com/+appPage/'
        });
    }


    SeoCollection.update(
        {
            route_name: 'homepage'
        },
        {
            $set: {
                route_name: 'homepage',
                title: ’title',
                meta: {
                    'description': ’siteDescription',
                    'keywords': ‘keyword, keyword, keyword',
                    'charset': 'utf-8',
                    'site_name': ’siteName',
                    'url':'http://siteName.com',
                    'viewport': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no',
                    'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=edge,chrome=1',
                    'HandheldFriendly': 'true',
                    'apple-mobile-web-app-capable' : 'yes',
                    'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style': 'black',
                    'referrer': 'never',
                },
                og: {
                    'title': ’siteTitle',
                    'description': ’siteDescription',
                    'image': 'image.png',
                    'type': 'website',
                    'locale': 'en_us',
                    'site_name': 'siteName',
                    'url': 'http://sitename.com'
                },
                rel_author: 'https://plus.google.com/+appPage/'
            }
        },
        {
            upsert: true
        }
    );

});
```

and dynamically using Iron:router -

```js
this.route('page:data', {
    path: '/page',
    onBeforeAction: function() {

      SEO.set({
        title: data.title,
        meta: {
          'description': 'description',
        },
        og: {
          'title': data.title,
          'description': 'description',
          'image': data.image
        }
      })
      
      this.next();
    }
  })
```

4. Submitting sitemaps using [gadicohen:sitemaps](https://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/sitemaps):

```js
sitemaps.add('/items.xml', function() {
  var out = [], pages = Collection.find().fetch();
  _.each(pages, function(page) {
    out.push({
      page: 'page/' + page.encodedUrl,
      lastmod: page.date,
    });
  });
  return out;
});
```

5. Using [meteor-up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) to deploy the app, it installs phantomJS. It combined with [spiderable](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spiderable) package enable google to crawl your app.

---

Problems I encounter:

1. Spiderable package works only in Google. It's true that it has the largest market share, but this way for 30% of SEO traffic from other search engines it works really bad.
2. I'm not sure if I should have all that stuff in seo.js file also in head tag. I know seo.js overwrites it, but when I request title from url on Reddit, it says no title tag find. It might be similar with other search engines from my perspective. But then there'd be multiple same tags, that is not good either.
3. What I'm doing good or wrong?

Comment: Check out this article, it worked great for me.
in a nutshell, it's a complete server side rendering, easy to use. give it a try. [Server side render for SEO](https://meteorhacks.com/meteor-server-sider-rendering-for-seo-purpose/)

Comment: Thanks, it looks really promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider [FlowRouter SSR](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/tree/ssr), which uses server-side rendering for HTTP requests. It generates the entire DOM on the server, and sends it as an initial static HTML `<body>`, thereby enabling all web spiders to crawl your site, not just Google. After that, your app will just continue to function as a real-time webapp, overriding the initial DOM.

It also supports subscriptions, thus you can use Mongo collections to render crawable content, too. But unfortunately it only works with React for now.

Comment: Wanted to give it try with the update I'm working on, but as you said unfortunately it only work with React now :/

Comment: I don't know how that's going to change, since Blaze templates are client-only code. Right now it's just another reason why learning React is a really good investment.

Comment: Browsing through the issues in the FlowRouter SSR repository I saw an item for Blaze. They were mentioning something about Blaze-components that is available in the server. The item is there just that no one has implemented the code yet.

Comment: I gave React try, but felt like just studying syntax for "just another framework". Its value over Blaze from my perspective wasn't worth the time. But if you're building a huge app, it seems to be a better option than Blaze.

Comment: Gonna give this ssr blaze package try and let you know how it works. Thanks for introducing SSR, it looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle this (atleast on my case), was using [prerender.io](http://prerender.io) + manuelschoebel:ms-seo in this way.

How?

Installing prerender, here you can use.

```
meteor add dfischer:prerenderio
```

**NOTE** If you get

```
res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead
```

You will have to use the npm package itself.

Now **Meta Tags.**

for this you can create a function like this.

```
setSEO = function(seoData){
  SEO.set({
          title: seoData.title,
          meta: {
            'description': seoData.description
          },
          og: {
            'title': seoData.title,
            'description': seoData.description,
            'image':seoData.image,
            'fb:app_id':seoData.appId
          }
        });
};
```

And then just call it on the `onAfterAction` hook

```
 Router.map(function() {
  self.route('route.name', {
    path: '/some',
    template: 'test',
    name: 'route.name',
    onAfterAction: function() {
      setSEO(pageData.seoData);
    }
  });
});
```

And thats it, on my side its working on twitter, g+, facebook, linkedin, pinterest.

Comment: I tried to use ms-seo + IronRouter in a similar way but the route gets called twice. I have opened an issue (https://github.com/DerMambo/ms-seo/issues/53) some time ago but I think the project is not active anymore. Have you noticed the same problem?

Comment: appendix: don't forget to remove spiderable.. dfischer:prerenderio and manuelschoebel:ms-seo (and iron:router obv) are the only packages you need..

Comment: Why everyone promote prerender.io? Isn't its method crawler identification by ?_escaped_fragment_= is deprecated? https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification#abstract Or I miss smth?

Comment: I have over 200.000 links, so this isn't really a solution for me. Went with Flow Router SSR approach instead.